# How to filter rows by matching columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have cust_SUBMISSION_DATE column in my dataframe. i took max of cust_SUBMISSION_DATE  and passed it to another column cust_SUBMISSION_DATE1 which was newly created. then i'm trying to filter rows which match both the columns.

```
cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE1']==cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE']
```

it is showing all true, but when tried to `filter` all rows like this

```
cust_df_3[cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE1']==cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE']]
(or)
cust_df_3.loc[cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE1']==cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE']]
```

getting less number of rows than expected

sample dataframe
[image]

only one unique value in both columns

Comment: Some sample data would help your question.

Comment: `it is showing all true` So if use `(cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE1']==cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE']).all()` it return `True` or `False` ?

Comment: yes it is returning true for all rows, but while filtering rows it's getting less

Comment: I think you are trying to do something done by `argmax` in `numpy`. `argmax` will give you all `indices` (rows number) where the value is maximum. For instance: `np.argmax(cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE'])`. [source](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax). If you want to return the dataframe filtered: `cust_df_3.iloc[np.argmax(cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE'])]` should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Although it should return all the rows when all are true, try out this:

```
cust_df_3.loc[cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE1']==cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE'], :]
```

or this one:

```
true_indices = []
for i in range(cust_df_3.shape[0]):
    if cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE1'][i]==cust_df_3['cust_SUBMISSION_DATE'][i]:
        true_indices.append(i)

cust_df_3.iloc[true_indices, :]
```